# How can I break a loop when I'm out of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fa-search', function () {

    while(1) {
        magnifire.fadeTo('slow', 0.2).fadeTo('slow', .8);
    }
    sendAjaxRequest();

    // Here I need to break (stop) that while loop
})
```

As I've commented in my code, I need to stop `while(1)` after `sendAjaxRequest();` executed. How can I do that?

Comment: did you try `break;`?

Comment: Posting the actual code would be useful, if you tried to run the code you posted, you'd never even reach sendAjaxRequest

Comment: @guradio I'm out of the `while()`, using `break;` is impossible methinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and `clearInterval` for this. As their names suggest, `setInterval` sets a function to execute repeatedly at given interval (1000 ms in example below), and `clearInterval` stops all further executions.

```js
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Do something");
  //  magnifire.fadeTo('slow', 0.2).fadeTo('slow', .8);
},1000);


function Clear() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  console.log("Stop iterating");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Clear()">Click me</button>
```